# In a title, can I omit "are you"? "(Are you) worried about climate change?"

Tags: questions, ellipsis, subject-pronoun-drop

I am a copywriter writing mainly in English, but this is not my native language. I'm using tools like Grammarly to make sure I make as few mistakes as possible and try to google my problems, but this one seems too complex for Google to handle.

I need to write an engaging title for a social network post/ landing page, which goes like this:
**Are you worried about climate change? Here are our tips for coping with climate anxiety.**

Is it acceptable to write:
**Worried about climate change? Here are our tips...**

I know that articles can be omitted from titles, and I think that "are you" can be omitted as well, but I can't find any source which explicitly states that.

Comment: Have you tried a partially 'advanced' Google search for (e.g.) "Are you worried about", also "Worried about", "worried about your"? Without much trouble I found _Worried about someone in prison?, Worried about a child?, Worried about your memory or dementia?, Worried about an Adult?, Worried about your teenager? Worried about your gambling?, Worried about your feelings?_

Comment: Try a reasonably thorough treatment of **ellipsis**.

Answer (score 2):

I am a native speaker from US - "Worried About Climate Change" really is fine. It sounds a little bit more casual or familiar.